# Overloading operator->() to change return value of called function

Tags: c++, c++14

Basically I'm doing this:

```
auto result = from (startNodePtr)
    .to<NodeT1>()
    .to<NodeT2>()
    .to<NodeT3>()
    .fail_with(msg)
```

chasing pointers. You can imagine "from" and "to" returning different
templates of a SyntaxSugar class and fail_with returning the result. Works fine.

But it's not that simple. Depending on the types of node I'm on I need to call
some operation on the underlying type. like this:

```
auto result = from(startNodePtr)
    .to<NodeT1>()
    .to<NodeT2>() -> SomeOperation()
    .to<NodeT3>()
    .fail_with(msg)
```

The operations will in turn return a Pointer, which I again need to wrap
in SyntaxSugar.

how would I overload operator-> correctly to do that?

Say my class looks like this:

```
template<typename Pointer_T>
class SyntaxSugar
{
  Pointer_T ptr;

public:
  explicit SyntaxSugar(Pointer_T ptr_)
    : ptr(ptr_)
  {}

  // all kinds of Syntax Sugar

  // this one I don't get to work:
  auto operator-> () { return SyntaxSugar(ptr.operator->()); }
}
```

Comment: You can overload `operator->` to auto-unwrap a pointer, but there is no way to automatically wrap the result of `SomeOperation` back into a `SyntaxSugar`  within that call chain unless it already returns that... The application of `SomeOperation` would have to happen inside some function "controlled" by you so that you can re-wrap the return value, and `operator->` cannot do that for you by itself. Would it be ok if every such operation had to be applied through a lambda (if it has other arguments)?

Comment: Basically, you could get a `...to<NodeT1>().apply([myParam](auto node){ node.SomeOperation(myParam); }).to<NodeT3>()`. Would that be too much boilerplate?

Comment: If the set of methods is not too large (and is not extensible), you could add them to `SyntaxSugar` so that they call the underlying method and rewrap.

Comment: @MaxLanghof `std::invoke` generalizes this to any invokable. `template<typename Op> auto apply(Op&& func) { return SyntaxSugar(std::invoke(func, ptr)); }` and this enables `.apply(&NodeT2::SomeOperation)`.

Answer (score 0):

That's amazing, @max-langhof

i basically now do

```
template<typename Op>
    auto SyntaxSugar::apply(Op func) -> decltype(SyntaxSugar(func(ptr)))
    { 
        if (!ptr) {
            fail();
            return SyntaxSugar(nullptr);
        }
        return SyntaxSugar(func(ptr));
    }
```

and now I can

```
auto result = from(startNodePtr)
    .to<NodeT1>()
    .to<NodeT2>()
    .apply([](auto node) { return node->SomeOperation(); })
    .to<NodeT3>()
    .fail_with(msg)
```